# Sub procedures have to be in alphabetical order. Really?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I rearranged the sub procedures in my forms into a logical sequence to make code maintenance easier. Everything was working fine until I decided to split the database. Straight after the split the forms would open OK but they didn't recognise any mouse actions like click and hover. It took me ages to realise that if I put the sub procedures back in alphabetical order then the problem would go away! Does anyone know why they have to be in order?

Comment: They don't. It must have been something else.

Comment: I think that somehow the code has become "detached" from the control, and by moving the code around, you have re-attached the code to the event.

Comment: Maybe `decompile` and `compact` the database via commandline.

Answer (score 1):

Just sounds like your subs became unlinked.

Access will sometimes remove the `[Event Procedure]` to bind an event if you remove a sub, and won't automatically add it back again if you place it somewhere else.

You can fix this by going to the controls, and pressing the button to add a procedure to the target event. This is a bit of an effort, but it usually doesn't happen. I've noted it when pasting subs to an external editor and then back again with a save in between.

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding. I think you're right Erik. Not sure how I did it but I was  copying and pasting from other forms so maybe that was enough to trigger it.